# How do I change this snippet to enable delegation on a form's ajax events?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form that is not included in the DOM when the page loads but rather another js function that dynamically adds the form to the DOM.  As I understand it, I need to enable delegation on this ".single-line-qualification" so that all existing and FUTURE instances respond in the same way.

How would I convert this snippet to use delegation of the form's ajax events?  Thanks for any help!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form.single-line-qualification')
    .on('ajax:before', function (e) {
      if (e.target[1].value.trim() === '') {
        e.target[1].value = '';
        alert('You must enter a name!');
        return false;
      }
    })
    .on('ajax:success', function (data, status, xhr) {
      // insert the data returned into the page
      $('#articles').append(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your looking for is called event bubbling. You have tried to define the event handler on an element that does not yet exist. However, with jQuery you can register the event on a parent element and let the event bubble up the tree. Look at this altered code snippet below. It should also be more performant if you define all your events on document and let them bubble up.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document)
  .on(
    'ajax:before',
    'form.single-line-qualification',
    function(e) {
      if (e.target[1].value.trim() === '') {
        e.target[1].value = '';
        alert('You must enter a name!');
        return false;
      }
    }
   )
   .on(
    'ajax:success',
    'form.single-line-qualification',
    function (data, status, xhr) {
      // insert the data returned into the page
      $('#articles').append(data);
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks cereal guy...flawless victory!